# Closed-form solution of non-autonomous vector recurrence relation

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, vectors, inner-products, recursion

In my research, I have recently come across the following problem involving a recurrence formula, the problem statement:

> We consider a given column vector $ x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_{d})^T \in \mathbb{R}^{d} $ and we define a column vector $ w = (w_1,w_2,...,w_{d})^T \in \mathbb{R}^{d} $ this denotes an initial condition of recurrence relation, and we define the following recursive relation 
>   $$w^{(n+1)} = w^{(n)}-\frac{2}{n}({w^{(n)}}^Tx-k)x$$ where $k$ is a nonnegative constant scalar, the initial condition is some arbitrary constant column vector $ w^{(1)} = (w_1,w_2,...,w_{d})^T=w \in \mathbb{R}^{d} $,

I was interested in finding a closed form for this recursive relation for  $w^{(n)}$ for any $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ as a function of the index $n$ and the initial condition $w$, can someone please assist here? I thank all helpers.

Comment: Looks like a snippet taken from a document. Is your answer not in there? Has the document nothing to say about the problem?

Comment: @Paul: It is a problem I formulated in my research in machine learning

Comment: @Paul : I meant $w$ is the form of the vector $ W^{(n)} $ they are one and the same but I edited the question so all $w$'s are lower case now

Comment: $w$ is the starting vector for the recursion then? you still have W in the question by the way.

Comment: @Paul: Yes but I have now used better notation for initial condition

Comment: If x has norm 1 then it is quick to see that $w^{(n)}=w^{(2)}$ for all $n\ge2$. If that helps!

Comment: @Paul well thats not always the case but thanks how do you see this it seems impossible to me?

Comment: Take the dot product with x then sub in n = 1,2, 3,  and see what you get. If the ${{\left\| x \right\|}^{2}}$ is an integer then you get a similar truncation when $n = 2{{\left\| x \right\|}^{2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rl} \mathrm w_{k+1} &= \mathrm w_{k} - \dfrac{2}{k} \left( \mathrm w_{k}^{\top} \mathrm x - \gamma\right) \mathrm x\\\\ &= \mathrm w_{k} - \dfrac{2}{k} \mathrm x \left( \mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm w_{k} - \gamma\right)\\\\ &= \left( \mathrm I - \dfrac{2}{k} \mathrm x \mathrm x^{\top} \right) \mathrm w_{k} + \left(\dfrac{2 \gamma}{k}\right) \mathrm x\end{array}$$

Let

$$\mathrm A_k := \mathrm I - \dfrac{2}{k} \mathrm x \mathrm x^{\top} \qquad \qquad \qquad \mathrm b_k := \left(\dfrac{2 \gamma}{k}\right) \mathrm x$$

Hence,

$$\mathrm w_k = \mathrm A_{k-1} \cdots \mathrm A_2 \mathrm A_1 \mathrm w_1 + \left(\sum_{m=1}^{k-2} \mathrm A_{k-1} \mathrm A_{k-2} \cdots \mathrm A_{m+1} \mathrm b_m\right) + \mathrm b_{k-1}$$

Comment: Thanks for the lovely answer could you please tell me what $I_n$ is?

Comment: $\mathrm I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: wouldn't that mean then that you are subtracting a scalar from a matrix?

Comment: No, because $\mathrm x \mathrm x^{\top}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: i think there is a mistake here you use n and k for the index and yet in the first recurrence equation you wrote you index w by k and you subtract a factor whose denominator is n whereas in my problem I wrote the fraction has denominator k meaning the index of the iteration

Comment: I mean if you index w by k there is no n in the problem

Comment: @zbigniew2015 You are absolutely correct. I will edit my answer.